# Python Pandas drop duplicate values from grouped data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am tracking how long people have had the same job. The real dataset is large, with lots of duplicate employee ids and jobs. I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

id= [2000,2001,2001,3000,2000,3000,3300,3300,3300,3300]
jtitle = ['job1','job2','job1','job3', 'job3', 'job2', 'job5', 'job5', 'job5', 'job6']
date = ['01/01/2021', '17/02/2018','17/02/2021', '01/01/2021', '25/03/2011', '11/11/2000', '22/01/2022', '15/12/2021', '11/11/2021', '10/09/2021']

data= pd.DataFrame(data=zip(id, jtitle, date), columns= ["id", "jtitle", "date"])
# convert to datetime object
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date, dayfirst=True)
#print(data)

# group employees by ID
latest = data.sort_values('date', ascending=False).groupby('id').nth(0)
#print(latest)

# find the latest point in time where there is a change in job title - but how?
prev_date = data.sort_values('date', ascending=False).groupby('id').nth(1).date
print(prev_date)
    
# calculate the difference in days
latest['days'] = latest.date - prev_date
print(latest)
```

Problem is, it only works if the same person is in the dataset only twice, which never happens in reality. I would need to somehow drop the jtitle duplicates in

```
prev_date = data.sort_values('date', ascending=False).groupby('id').nth(1).date
```

but if I put in .unique(), I get the error message "AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'unique'". The current output of the code shows:

```
jtitle       date      days
id                              
2000   job1 2021-01-01 3570 days
2001   job1 2021-02-17 1096 days
3000   job3 2021-01-01 7356 days
3300   job5 2022-01-22   38 days
```

The desired output would be correcting the error of "38 days", which is around 134 days.
Does anyone know how to fix it or solve the problem in another way, please?

Editing for clarity: so many kind users provided answers but unfortunately all throw errors in the real dataset :-(

Dataset is a large data frame with fields "id", "jtitle", "date".
The date is when the data was pulled from the system, and there are about 200 data extracts appended. This means that the same id may be in the dataset 200 times. Job titles may change, change back, stay the same.
What I need to do is:

1. Find the most recent date associated with every id.
2. Going back in time find the date when that person's job title was different.
3. Calculate the number of days between the two dates. In other words: how many days has this person had their most recent job title?
   I am interested only in the most recent one (so if a person has had 5 different job titles, I only need the number of days between the most recent and the one before. If someone is in the dataset only once, I still need them there with a NA or something.

I hope this helps and someone can solve this for me :-|

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking, provide better explanation and show us your expected result

Comment: @eshirvana, the expected result is 134 in the last column, last row, for the reasons explained in the first paragraph. What I am asking is in the title of the post.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question but why aren't you using `.first()` and `.last()` and using instead `.nth(0)` and `.nth(1)`? If you want the latest point in time then using `.last()` will work.

Comment: I suspect `nth(-1)` to work as well but `.last()` as @Ryno_XLI suggested is more understandable.

Comment: @Ryno_XLI, wouldn't last() give me the earliest job? I.e. someone had job1 this year, job2 last year and job3 in 1998. I would like to know how long s/he has had the present job, not the difference between the current and their very first. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Thank you **very** much for the kind and quick responses, @vpz, Emma, piterbarg. I have accepted the answer that was most similar to my original code, but **all** your help is greatly appreciated and I will ponder over all the solutions. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing, always pleasure. Good choice as long as you have at most two  distinct jtitle's per id in your real data

Comment: @piterbarg, no, often a lot more, but currently only tracking the most recent one ("job stagnation"). Your point is taken though!

Comment: @vpz, sorry, I have just run your code on the real dataset and it gives incorrect results. when someone has a job sequence of "job1, job1, job1, job2, job2", your code calculates the time between the two end-points, which is no good for me.

Comment: I'd suggest that you edit your question and add an example(s) that is more complicated than what you have now and covers various cases of interest to you, with expected output, so different solutions can be tested

Answer (score 2):

You should use the method [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) from pandas.

The following should solve your problem.

Yours code:

```
import pandas as pd

id= [2000,2001,2001,3000,2000,3000,3300,3300,3300,3300]
jtitle = ['job1','job2','job1','job3', 'job3', 'job2', 'job5', 'job5', 'job5', 'job6']
date = ['01/01/2021', '17/02/2018','17/02/2021', '01/01/2021', '25/03/2011', '11/11/2000', '22/01/2022', '15/12/2021', '11/11/2021', '10/09/2021']

data= pd.DataFrame(data=zip(id, jtitle, date), columns= ["id", "jtitle", "date"])
# convert to datetime object
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date, dayfirst=True)
```

Solution:

```
# subset employees by ID, sort by date and drop duplicates
latest = data.sort_values('date', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='first').copy()

prev_date = data.sort_values('date', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last').copy()
    
# calculate the difference in days
latest['days'] = latest['date'].values -  prev_date['date'].values
print(latest)
```

Output:

```
  id jtitle       date      days
3300   job5 2022-01-22  134 days
2001   job1 2021-02-17 1096 days
2000   job1 2021-01-01 3570 days
3000   job3 2021-01-01 7356 days
```

Comment: I do not think this will work when there are more than two distinct jtitle's per id. This is not the case in the example provided by the OP but they did allude to the real df being more complicated

Comment: @piterbarg, that's a good point. Currently I am only tracking how long a person has had their current job, so I only need it between the most recent and the previous one.

Comment: @Reader123 not to beat the dead horse, but just so you are aware and not caught by surprise when you apply this to your real data, but I believe this solution will give you a difference in days between the _earliest_ and the _latest_ jtitle not the last and the one before last

Comment: @piterbarg, I was so excited about this code that I have actually logged back into work to try and I am this very minute discovering **exactly** what you are saying.. :-(

Comment: @piterbarg, just ran your code, I am getting negative numbers of days in a handful of cases, including ones where start date and end date in your output are the same, but the number of days is -91 :-|

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution with `diff` and `sum`.

```
data['days'] = data.sort_values('date').groupby('id').date.diff()
data = data.groupby(['id', 'jtitle']).agg({'days': 'sum', 'date': 'first'}).reset_index()

# to filter to only more than 0 days
data[data.days.dt.days > 0]
```

Result

```
     id jtitle      days       date
0  2000   job1 3570 days 2021-01-01
1  2001   job1 1096 days 2021-02-17
2  3000   job3 7356 days 2021-01-01
3  3300   job5  134 days 2022-01-22
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve (eg the `date` column -- is this the date a person starts that job? finishes it?) but let's give it a go

first we aggregate by`id` and `jtitle` and find the earliest and the latest date that corresponds to that combo:

```
df = (data.groupby(['id','jtitle'], sort=False)
        .agg(start_date = ('date','min'), end_date = ('date','max'))
        .reset_index().sort_values(['id','start_date'], ascending = True)
)
```

`df` looks like this:

```
      id  jtitle    start_date           end_date
--  ----  --------  -------------------  -------------------
 4  2000  job3      2011-03-25 00:00:00  2011-03-25 00:00:00
 0  2000  job1      2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-01-01 00:00:00
 1  2001  job2      2018-02-17 00:00:00  2018-02-17 00:00:00
 2  2001  job1      2021-02-17 00:00:00  2021-02-17 00:00:00
 5  3000  job2      2000-11-11 00:00:00  2000-11-11 00:00:00
 3  3000  job3      2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-01-01 00:00:00
 7  3300  job6      2021-09-10 00:00:00  2021-09-10 00:00:00
 6  3300  job5      2021-11-11 00:00:00  2022-01-22 00:00:00
```

Now we get the `days` column by grouping by `id` and within each group subtracting end-date from the previous row (ie previous job) from the end_date of the current row (job). We also drop NaNs

```
df2 = (df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: g.assign(days = g['end_date']-g['end_date'].shift()))
        .dropna()
        .reset_index(drop = True)
    )
```

`df2`:

```
      id  jtitle    start_date           end_date             days
--  ----  --------  -------------------  -------------------  ------------------
 0  2000  job1      2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-01-01 00:00:00  3570 days 00:00:00
 1  2001  job1      2021-02-17 00:00:00  2021-02-17 00:00:00  1096 days 00:00:00
 2  3000  job3      2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-01-01 00:00:00  7356 days 00:00:00
 3  3300  job5      2021-11-11 00:00:00  2022-01-22 00:00:00  134 days 00:00:00
```

**Note that this works for more than two different `jtitle`s per id**

for example, with another job, `job7`, added for id=3300 (last row)

```
id= [2000,2001,2001,3000,2000,3000,3300,3300,3300,3300,3300]
jtitle = ['job1','job2','job1','job3', 'job3', 'job2', 'job5', 'job5', 'job5', 'job6', 'job7']
date = ['01/01/2021', '17/02/2018','17/02/2021', '01/01/2021', '25/03/2011', '11/11/2000', '22/01/2022', '15/12/2021', '11/11/2021', '10/09/2021', '07/09/2023']

data= pd.DataFrame(data=zip(id, jtitle, date), columns= ["id", "jtitle", "date"])
```

the output would be

```
    id  jtitle  start_date  end_date    days
0   2000    job1    2021-01-01  2021-01-01  3570 days
1   2001    job1    2021-02-17  2021-02-17  1096 days
2   3000    job3    2021-01-01  2021-01-01  7356 days
3   3300    job5    2021-11-11  2022-01-22  134 days
4   3300    job7    2023-09-07  2023-09-07  593 days
```